GCP workflow condition using like %string%
May I know if workflow can use like, contained, or match?
I know can use == to be the condition, but how about like?
 - Test: switch: - condition: ${Test like %complete%} steps: - Complete  next: Not_started
Thanks
I have tried using like, match, and contained, but cannot work
